# How to generate permutations of restricted substutions?

Tags: php, algorithm, combinatorics

It's best explained with an example.

Let say you have a list of substitutions, will use PHP because that's my target:

```
$s = array(
    'p' => array('b', 'f', 'v'),
    'a' => array('e'),
    't' => array('d', '')
);
```

The above means that 'p' can be replaced by 'b', 'f', or 'v'; 'a' by 'e'; and 't' by 'd' or nothing. Only one substitution of each list is allowed at a time.

So generating all substitutions of 'pa' would give: 'ba', 'fa', 'va', 'pe', 'be', 'fe', 've'

And generating all substitutions of 'papa': 'baba', 'fafa', 'vava', 'pepe' 'bebe', 'fefe', 'veve'

I can permute through the upper elements easy enough:

```
// 2 ^ count($s) permutations, assuming count($s) < 31
$k = 1 << count($s);
for ($l = 0; $l < $k; $l++)
{
    $x = $input;
    for ($m = $l, reset($s); $m; $m >>= 1, next($s))
        if ($m & 1)
            // Will fail here, maybe this should be an outer loop but how?
            // For now, just replacing with the first element
            $x = str_replace(key($s), current($s)[0], $x);
    print $x."\n";
}
```

Just can't wrap my head around how to do the inner substitutions correctly.

I considered transforming $s to a series of simple substitutions:

```
$t = array(
    array('p' => 'b'),
    array('a' => 'e'),
    array('p' => 'b', 'a' => 'e'),
    array('p' => 'f'),
    ...
```

But that still gets me back to the same problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jason McCreary's answer as inspiration, I found a solution that uses minimal memory. The largest the array $X can get is Π(|permutation list|), so for the example below 3×1×2 = 6.

```
$input = 'pat';

$S = array(
    'p' => array('b', 'f', 'v'),
    'a' => array('e'),
    't' => array('d', '')
);

// 2 ^ count($S) permutations, assuming count($S) < 31
for ($k = 1 << count($S), $l = 0; $l < $k; $l++)
{
    $X = array($input);
    for ($m = $l, reset($S); $m; $m >>= 1, next($S))
        if ($m & 1)
        {
            $w = key($S);
            $Y = $X;
            $X = array();
            foreach ($Y as $y)
                foreach (current($S) as $s)
                    $X[] = str_replace($w, $s, $y);
        }

    foreach ($X as $x)
        print $x.' ';
}
print "\n";
```

Output:

```
pat bat fat vat pet bet fet vet pad pa bad ba fad fa vad va ped pe bed be fed fe ved ve
```

Answer (score 1):

Your management of `for` loops combined with array pointers is overly complex.

The following is a very naive approach which likely could be streamlined by adopting other strategies such as recursion.

```
function generate_permutations($subtitutions, $subject) {
    $permutations = array($subject);

    foreach ($subtitutions as $search => $replacements) {
        $new_permutations = array();

        foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {
            foreach ($permutations as $permutation) {
                if (strpos($permutation, $search) === false) {
                    continue;
                }

                $new_permutations[] = str_replace($search, $replacement, $permutation);
            }
        }

        $permutations = array_merge($permutations, $new_permutations);
    }

    return $permutations;
}
```

**Note:** I only tested with your examples.

Comment: Thank you. In your code, if there are a lot of permutations, the memory requirements increase exponentially. But I took inspiration from your code to revise it accordingly.